# What are those #text in childNodes in JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am facing an issue in JS code.

Here is my html:

```html
<h1>
When
<!-- Green highlight effect -->
<span class="highlight">banking</span>
meets <br/>
<span class="highlight">minimalist</span>
</h1>
```

and when I try to get child nodes of that h1 element I see `#text` in a `NodeList` at various points such as
`document.querySelector('h1').childNodes[2]`.

Can someone explain how and why this is showing? Because there is no text after the comment there is a span and then there is a text element but not at [2]

I'm trying to get child nodes but there are some elements which I do not expect to be there.

Comment: _"because there is no text after the comment"_ - **yes there is**: whitespace chars (the spaces and `\r\n` line-breaks) exist between the `-->` and the `<span>`, that's what's inside the `#text` node. You can avoid this by using `Element.children` instead of `Node.childNodes`: the `children` property only returns `Element` children (and omits `#text` node children).

Comment: It's a [`Text` node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). Look at its `.value` to see what content is